# No implementation for play.api.Application was bound

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

With Play 2.4, after adding new modules for dependency injection, I got this error:

```
No implementation for play.api.Application was bound.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `application/conf`:

```
play.modules.enabled = ...
```

should have been:

```
play.modules.enabled += ...
```

preserving Play's own module list including  `play.api.Application` and appending to it instead of replacing.

Comment: For anyone coming here and using the code approach, do not use `loadModule(myModule)` but `overrides(myModule)`